# NPM install gulp --save-dev error

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm trying to get set up on a project with Gulp.js when I run the command:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

I get the errors:

```
npm WARN package.json htdocs@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json gulp-uglify@1.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json gulp@3.8.8 No README data
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, chown '/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, chown '/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json']
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES, chown \'/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json',
npm ERR!   fstream_finish_call: 'chown',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack:
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:308:19',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:143:7',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:93:15)' ] }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-12-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /path/to/dir/htdocs
npm ERR! node -v v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.26
npm ERR! path /path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chown
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, chown '/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/gulp/package.json'
npm ERR! stack     at Error (native)
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:308:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:143:7
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:93:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/to/dir/htdocs/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "htdocs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I found a few people with similar issues online and the fixes suggested running the command:

> sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
>   But this has not solved the issue in my case.

Does anyone have an idea what the cause of this could be and a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on OSX, I fixed it executing:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
```

and:

```
npm cache clean
```

Then I could install the package with `--save-dev` in the project.

Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5869

Answer (score 0):

npm must be able to write into the path `/path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/`, where (your) node writes its modules.

You have two frequently-used options to fix these permissions:

- Install one gulp for everyone

  ```
  sudo npm install -g gulp
  ```
- Save gulp for project

  ```
  (sudo if necessary) chmod u+rw /path/to/dir/htdocs/node_modules/
  npm install gulp --save-dev
  ```

  You may also need to fix permissions for parent directories.

If anyone else has a better idea, please also let me know.

Answer (score 0):

running 
npm install npm@latest -g
and updating to the latest version solved the issue for me :)